# Coding a plot with functions

Tags: r

So I've probably referenced the entire internet trying to make this problem work, and haven't. However, I found stack overflow. Like I said I've been learning for not even 2 weeks yet.

**So this is the problem**

1. Let
   f(x)=sqrt((x^3+3x^2+1)/(x^4+5x^3+7x+9))
   (x ≥ 0)
   (a) Draw a line graph of (x, f(x)) for 0 ≤ x ≤ 10 with increments of 0.01
   (b) Find numerically the maximum value of f(x) and the maximizer x (report x to the
   second decimal place. For instance, x = 1.23)

So I'm basically been saying x=x and y= the sqrt....., and then I write plot(x,y,type="l") and usually it just doesn't even work.
Also how do I do the increment part. I'm sorry for lack of explanation, but I have no idea what most of this means.

Comment: can you show us (edit your question to include) some of your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a `ggplot2` approach. First you have to create a random `x` variable and then compute `y`. I will add the code for that variables an the plot.

In the case of finding the maximum of `f(x)` you must know calculus or you can use a visual approach. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
```

First we create a random variable `x` with the limits you mentioned:

```
#Data
x <- runif(100,0,10)
```

Now, we save the variable in a dataframe and compute `y`:

```
#Allocate data in a dataframe
df <- data.frame(x=x)
#Compute variable
df$y <- sqrt(((df$x^3)+3*((df$x)^2)+1)/((df$x^4)+5*(df$x)^3+7*(df$x)+9))
```

Finally, we plot:

```
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,10))
```

Output:

[image]

Values for `x` are randomly generated, if you have real values for `x` you should use those values.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do would be to define the function:

```
equation <- function(x){
sqrt((x^3+3*x^2+1)/(x^4+5*x^3+7*x+9))
}
```

Then, define the values you want to apply the function to, and store them in vector `input`

```
input<-seq(0,10,0.01)
```

Apply the `equation` function to `input`, and store the values in vector `results`

```
results<-sapply(input,function)
```

Produce a line plot:

```
plot(input,results,type="l")
```

Print the value of x which maximises f(x)

```
maxx<-input[which.max(results)]
maxx
```